# Resizing of ref-element not captured in React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I'm working with d3js and reactjs.
I want to (re-)size my d3-plot to the size of the containing `div`.

In my component I create a `ref` using `useRef` and reference the container div. I extract the `dimensions` of the div using `useMemo` and pass the dimensions to the Plot component and use it there to size the Plot accordingly. This all works fine, but when I resize the page, **`dimensions` does not update**.

I tried to change the dependency of the `useMemo` hook from `ref` to `ref.current`, but this does not help.

My current solution is using a custom hook, that captures `window.resize`-Events and passes me the `width` and `height` of the `window`, which I then use as additional dependencies of the `useMemo` hook. This however gives me an ugly `exhaustiv-deps` lint, so I guess this is not the way to go to achieve such trivial behavior. What is a more elegant solution?

(I'm using the `useMemo` hook because `dimensions` is a dependency inside the Plot component of some expensive function, which should only get called again on resize)

**Not updating on resize:**

```js
const ref = useRef();

const dimensions = useMemo(() => {
    return {
        width: ref?.current?.offsetWidth,
        height: ref?.current?.offsetHeight,
    };
}, [ref]);

return (
    <div ref={ref}>
        <MyPlot dimensions={dimensions}/>
    </div>
(
```

**Resizing but with lint-warning:**

```js
const [width, height] = useResize()
const ref = useRef();

const dimensions = useMemo(() => {
    return {
        width: ref?.current?.offsetWidth,
        height: ref?.current?.offsetHeight,
    };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [ref.current, width, height]);

return (
    <div ref={ref}>
        <MyPlot dimensions={dimensions}/>
    </div>
(
```

**useResize hook**

```js
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useResize() {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth); 
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);

    const handleWindowSizeChange = useCallback(() => {
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    }, [setWidth, setHeight]);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        };
    }, [handleWindowSizeChange]);

    return [width, height];
}
```

Comment: Do you even need to re-"memoize" the height and width? It also doesn't seem you even use the `height` and `width` values returned from the `useResize` hook. Can you just pass the `height` and `width` directly to `MyPlot`, i.e. `<MyPlot dimensions={{ height, width }}/>`?

Comment: I only use the `height` and `width` to ***trigger*** the `useMemo` hook and update the dimensions. I can not pass the dimensions directly to `MyPlot` because they are used inside `MyPlot` to update a expensive function, which would then be called again and again on each render, which then breaks the fluidness of the interactivity of the plot

Comment: Then I suppose you don't need the `useResize` hook since you're not using it and are getting the wrapper `div`'s dimensions and passing that into `MyPlot`. What are the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning you are seeing? I guess using the window's height/width to trigger the `useMemo` hook makes sense. It's still unclear what is, or isn't, working and what your question really is.

Comment: The `react-hooks/exhaustive-dep` warning is that i should not use height/width to update the `useMemo` hook.
The code is working but the warning seems to me to indicate a code smell. 
If i just pass in the dimensions of ref directly to `MyPlot`, how is a `useEffect` hook inside `MyPlot` going to know that it should trigger or not, given dimensions is in its dependency array?